# How to iterate through key/value pair in javascript, if I dont know key name

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json like:

```
var json = [{"Google":[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
                {"Linkedin":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
                {"Uber":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
                {"Akamai":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
                {"Apple":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
                {"Hulu":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
                {"IBM":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
                {"Spotify":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
                {"Amazon":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}];
```

I want to iterate through it.
json.length returns 9 => implying there are 9 key/value pairs in this json. How can I find key at index 0 and its corresponding value in javascript.

I tried using something like:

```
$.each(json, function(k, v) {
        //display the key and value pair
        alert(k + ' is ' + v);
    });
```

but here key is returning 1,2,3... and value as [object object]

Comment: Your json var is an array that contains json object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Use [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate through the `array` and [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) over iterated item to get all the `keys` of individual object.

```js
var json = [{
  "Google": [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
}, {
  "Linkedin": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
}, {
  "Uber": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
}, {
  "Akamai": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
}, {
  "Apple": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
}, {
  "Hulu": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
}, {
  "IBM": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
}, {
  "Spotify": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
}, {
  "Amazon": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
}];
json.forEach(function(item) {
  var keys = Object.keys(item);
  console.log(keys);
  //to get the values
  keys.forEach(function(key) {
    console.log(item[key]);
  })
});
```

Comment: Thanks this is working. But, how can I get corresponding value? Something like "var values = Object.values(item);" ?.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I find key at index 0 and its corresponding value in
>   javascript.

You can get all the key names in an object by using `Object.keys` method.

try

```
var key0 = Object.keys(json[0])[0];
```

this will give you key name at index 0.

And

```
value0 = json[0][key0];
```

This can be made more generic to iterate through entire `json`

```
json.forEach(function(val){
   var key = Object.keys(val)[0];
   var value = val[key];
   console.log( "key is " + key );
   console.log( "value is " + value );
});
```

Comment: This is one piece of a possible answer, but does not answer the question about how to iterate through all the key/value pairs.

Comment: @jfriend00 Not sure if user had asked for it since he already knew how to iterate, OP simply asked how to get the key name at every index

Answer (score 1):

You should consider re-formatting your JSON data.

I personally think it's good practice to give each value an appropriate "attribute" when using JSON Objects (Giving "Google" an attribute of "company") for easier access to the values & readability.

EG:

```
var json = [{'company':"Google",'values':[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
            {'company':"Linkedin",'values':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
            {'company':"Uber",'values':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
            {'company':"Akamai",'values':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
            {'company':"Apple",'values':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
            {'company':"Hulu",'values':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
            {'company':"IBM",'values':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
            {'company':"Spotify",'values':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
            {'company':"Amazon",'values':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}];
```

Then, you can iterate through the values by using 2 $.each loops. One nested after the other.

```
$.each(json,function(key,val){

   var company = val.company;
   console.log('Below values belong to '+company);

   $.each(val.values,function(k,v){
     var value = v;
     console.log(value);
   });

   console.log('End of values belonging to '+company);
});
```

To find the key (I assume by key you mean the company name) at index 0, you can access the json array with the index of 0 as such.

```
var company = json[0].company;
var valueArray = json[0].values;
```

Answer (score 1):

something like this

```js
var json = [{"Google":[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
                {"Linkedin":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
                {"Uber":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
                {"Akamai":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
                {"Apple":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
                {"Hulu":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
                {"IBM":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
                {"Spotify":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
                {"Amazon":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}];

json.forEach(function(n){  
  Object.keys(n).forEach(function(x) { 
    document.writeln(x + ' is ' + n[x] + '</br>');  
  }) 
}) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will be useful

```
var json = [
                {"Google":[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
                {"Linkedin":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
                {"Uber":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
                {"Akamai":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
                {"Apple":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
                {"Hulu":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
                {"IBM":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
                {"Spotify":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
                {"Amazon":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}
             ];

     json.forEach(function(key,value){
     var _getCurrentItem = key; // will give google:Array[18]....
     // Loop through this object to get its key & value
         for(var keys in _getCurrentItem){ 
         console.log('Key is ' + keys +' & its value' +_getCurrentItem[keys]);
     })
```

Check this [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/1rvz3696/4/) for working model

Answer (score 1):

[] represents an array which means the keys are integers : 0 to (N-1) : N is the number of items in the array/list. i.e. : `var t = ["Me", "You", "Them"];` where `t[0] is "Me"` and `t[2] is "Them"`.

{} represents an object or associative array : an array with string keys. i.e. `var t = {"firstperson" : "me", "secondperson" : "you", "thirdperson" : "them"};` where `t["firstperson"] is "me"`.

So, in your data representation, you should have two loops, one within the other :

```
$.each(json, function(k, v) {
    //display the key and value pair
    $.each(v, function(k2, v2) {
            //display the key and value pair
            alert('json[' + k + '][' + k2 + '] = ' + v2);
        });
});
```